# Elections are unaware of the uploadable avatar system

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, profile-picture

The most recent Stack Overflow election nominee, ChrisF, noticed something interesting. His avatar on Stack Overflow is [a dog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHxhf.jpg?s=128&g=1), but on his post on the election page, it shows [his face instead](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ee006a67bbbb535dc04afc6a03b1843f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG). And on hover, the avatar slowly transitions from the latter into the former in the hovercard.

[BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) identified that this appears to be because the dog picture is a self-uploaded image using our new avatar service, while his face is a product of his Gravatar. As such, the nomination page seems to ignore which avatar setting the user is using, opting to always choose Gravatar. Great for those who use Gravatar, not so much otherwise.

This can be confirmed with a couple of the other current candidates. It's somewhat minor in the long scheme of things, but it is disorienting, especially as for some folks it will give them a generic auto-gen Gravatar when in actuality their profile image is a custom pic.

Comment: ChrisF isn't a dog?!

Comment: I *knew* something wasn't right with so many candidates bearing auto-generated icons...

Comment: Hmm, and the code changes for the statistics page will need to be deployed to fix this there too.

Comment: This is especially comical with Jon Clements avatar choices. :-)

Comment: Huh, mouseover pops up a box that shows the real icons for everyone except Flexo, for whom it seems to do nothing at all (in Chrome on XP anyway)

Comment: @Wooble He may not have the popup configured.

Comment: @Wooble Flexo has a blank "About Me".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well spotted; this has been rectified and will be deployed momentarily.

Comment: Yay! [I'm now my dog](http://stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-15137866)

Comment: If you try to add your Flair image to your nomination you get a [rejection message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRXdF.png) claiming it's for spam prevention purposes. That's odd because you are allowed to add images and if the Community Manager caught someone uploading an inappropriate image future transgressions would surely be prevented - it's not as though I can't upload images everywhere else, or that one doesn't require a minimum amount of reputation to run for election in the first place. Safe to say images aren't handled the same as elsewhere.